# How to Sum output of a Powershell command

Tags: powershell

i have written a one-liner to sum up the space of all Exchange Mailboxes. It's like

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-Mailbox  | where {$_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailBox"} | Get-MailboxStatistics | measure-Obj
ect -Property TotalItemSize -sum
Measure-Object : Das Eingabeobjekt "42.32 MB (44,377,424 bytes)" ist nicht numerisch.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:99
+ Get-Mailbox  | where {$_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailBox"} | Get-MailboxStatistics | measure-Object <<<<  -Property To
talItemSize -sum
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (42.32 MB (44,377,424 bytes):Unlimited`1) [Measure-Object], PSInvalidOperat
   ionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

which, as seen, is not working cause the output of that Object is not a numeric value.
So, how to get the SUM working?

Comment: Use a property that is numeric. Run `... | Get-MailboxStatistics | Get-Member` to see what is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `TotalItemSize` is of type `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize` try the following:

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | ForEach-Object {[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::Parse($_.TotalItemSize)} | Measure-Object -Sum
```

Comment: And i hoped that there is a more easy solution. Just a output in Byte as default, but seems not.